# Sql Server benchmarking - Clarifications

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-testing, query-performance

We are in process of enabling both TDE and EFS on our DBs. In process of performance benchmarking to understand how sql server is behaving on current hardware pre and post , we are using perfmon or any third party tool which we use for resource performance counters ..  they give us only average of counter values and not spikes whenever the Processor Time or Available MBytes hit 99% or above values ... correct ? If I am wrong please correct me ..

My question is how to look at even when and at what time the processor or RAM is at highest point ? Kindly advise and correct my understanding.

Comment: Sounds like this would be better directed towards the product vendor, I haven't heard of or used this before personally.

Comment: Agree with you @LowlyDBA . May be this is new product we are using. How about perfmon does this have the capability to load all details above  and it is not recommended to continously turn it on in PROD correct !

Comment: Also to remove false understanding I removed the tool name and set it as any third party tool... Just needed some advise out of expertise. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

> We are in process of enabling both TDE and EFS on our DBs.

You're not really considering enabling both TDE and EFS on your SQL Server Databases at the same time, right?

> My question is how to look at even when and at what time the processor or RAM is at highest point ?

You can capture performance counters as frequently as you like.  In particular a Perfmon Data Collector Set can be configured to capture every 1 second.